# Adding autocomplete email address list in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am try to add autocomplete list email in my function. Right now, i key in the email address manually, so i have to write or copy all. it should be more efficient if the there autocomplete feature. Here is my code sample:

```
function getemail(){

  var ui_user = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui_user.prompt("Enter Receiver Email:");
  return result.getResponseText();

}
```

is GAS can search our contacts email address then query it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google Apps Script could be used to search for contacts by using the [Contacts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts) but it's not possible to add autocomplete feature the `Spreadsheet.Ui.prompt`. In order to have that feature you will have to create a [dialog by using HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), client side code (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) and [communicate this code with server code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en).